# Google Analytics (v3.03) for iOS - not receiving data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am having a wired problem with Google analytics for iOS.
According to console, it seems that I am sending data, but when I look at realtime overview in Google Analytics, I see no response from my actions in the app.

This is how I have implemented the tracker:

In AppDelegate.h:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Start Google Analytics
    [GAI sharedInstance].dryRun = NO;
    [[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = kGANDispatchPeriodSec; // 10 secs
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kGANAccountId]; // UA-XXXXXX-XX
    [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker;
```

In MyViewController.h:
    #import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

```
@interface FRAdviceViewController : GAITrackedViewController {
    ...
}
```

In MyViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *godeRaadPath = @"/godeRåd/";
    //[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:[godeRaadPath stringByAppendingString:advice.title] withError:nil];
    self.screenName = [godeRaadPath stringByAppendingString:advice.title];

    ...
}
```

Basically, I set the screenName and hope that the GAITrackedViewController will do it's thing.

I get the following message in console when loading the viewController:

```
2014-04-23 11:47:46.889 TÆNK[256:3303] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:418): Saved hit: {
parameters =     {
    "&_u" = ".o";
    "&_v" = "mi3.0.3c";
    "&an" = "T\U00c6NK";
    "&av" = "1.8.2";
    "&cd" = "/s\U00e5danHarViTestetArtikel/S\U00e5dan har vi testet br\U00f8dristere";
    "&cid" = "d1c5e459-ed0b-49d0-b532-f81fb9ff1d85";
    "&sr" = 320x480;
    "&t" = appview;
    "&tid" = "UA-1418061-9";
    "&ul" = da;
    "&v" = 1;
    "&z" = 15611112842331434332;
    gaiVersion = "3.03c";
};
timestamp = "2014-04-23 09:47:46 +0000";
}
2014-04-23 11:47:56.914 TÆNK[256:3303] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:177): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2014-04-23 11:47:56.923 TÆNK[256:3303] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:503): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=1.8.2&cd=%2Fs%C3%A5danHarViTestetArtikel%2FS%C3%A5dan+har+vi+testet+br%C3%B8dristere&t=appview&ul=da&_u=.o&tid=UA-1418061-9&cid=d1c5e459-ed0b-49d0-b532-f81fb9ff1d85&v=1&sr=320x480&_v=mi3.0.3c&an=T%C3%86NK&ht=1398246466879&qt=10034&z=15611112842331434332
2014-04-23 11:47:57.210 TÆNK[256:60b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2014-04-23 11:47:57.214 TÆNK[256:3303] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:430): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2014-04-23 11:47:57.225 TÆNK[256:3303] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:167): 1 hit(s) sent
```

What confuses me is, that it says: "HTTP status 200", "hit(s) successfully dispatched" and "1 hit(s) sent" - when I get no response on RealTime graphs.

(Tested on iPhone 4)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: 
I should have been a bit more specific.
Our current version of the app has implemented Google Analytics already (but an older version, and XCode wont build with that version).
So I do see some activities on RealTime. When I use the current version with old analytics, it works just fine and shows in realtime.
But the test devices with my updated version of analytics don't show up.

Comment: Where are you looking for your data? The real-time reports should show it instantly.  The Standard reports can take up to 24 hours for your data to appear.

Comment: I am looking at real-time. Real-time --> Overview.

Comment: and your sure "UA-1418061-9" is the right account? Don't laugh I have seen it happen :)

Comment: It is the correct ID. But that was my first thought as well ;)

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Run into the same problem with 3.0.9. Logs show that it is successfully submitted but not showing up on google analytics web site.

Answer (score 0):

There is one nice uncleared issue that is not declared anywhere.

When you are starting to work with analytics for the first time. You go through few steps up to generating a config file. After you created and `Downloaded config files` and download `GoogleService-Info.plist` google automatically create `credentials -> API keys`:

- Browser key (auto created by Google Service)
- Server key (auto created by Google Service)
- iOS key (auto created by Google Service)

**With the status:**

> This API key is unrestricted. To prevent unauthorized use and quota
>   theft, restrict your key to limit how it can be used.

*That's why analytics is not collecting your data.*

**You need to go through few steps:**

1. Go to [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Select `a project`
3. In the list of `API keys` click on unrestricted key - the form will appear
4. In section `Key restriction` select `iOS apps`
5. Set `Accept requests from an iOS application with one of these bundle identifiers`
6. **Save**

That`s all. And now Analytics will start to collect data.